# Nested liquid loops in a Jekyll archive page not working. Using an outer loop variable inside the inner's condition

Tags: ruby, liquid, jekyll

I am working with the jekyll static site builder, and I am having 
difficulty performing the following:

```
{% for category in site.categories %} 
<h2 id = "{{ category[0] }}"> {{ category[0] }} </h2> 
        {% for post in site.categories[{{ category }}] %} 
                <li> <a href="{{ post.url }}"> {{ post.title }}</a></li> 
        {% endfor %} 
<a href="#{{ category[0] }}-ref">&#8617</a> 
{% endfor %}
```

I have a post category in my jekyll site called 'test', and I can 
display posts from it with the following:

```
{% for post in site.categories.test %} 
                <li> <a href="{{ post.url }}"> {{ post.title }}</a></li> 
{% endfor %}
```

However, i want to build an archive page automatically, and in order 
to do this, I need to embed the category from the outer loop (the loop 
that visits all the categories), and use it inside the inner loop to 
access posts from that specific category. What do I need to do to get 
the first snippet to work how I want it to?

EDIT: Alternatively, is there another way to get the results that I want?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you do `for category in site.categories` ,

- `category[0]` will give you the category name,
- `category[1]` will give you the list of posts for that category.

That's the way Liquid handles iteration over hashes, I believe.

So the code you are looking for is this one:

```
{% for category in site.categories %} 
<h2 id="{{ category[0] }}-ref">{{ category[0] }}</h2>
<ul>
  {% for post in category[1] %} 
    <li><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li> 
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
<p><a href="#{{ category[0] }}-ref">&#8617;</a></p>
{% endfor %}
```

I've taken the liberty of fixing some markup issues - I've added `<ul>...</ul>` around the post link list, a `<p>` around the last link, a semi-colon after the `8617`, and also fixed the `id` at the top (was missing the `-ref` part).

Regards!

Comment: The <p> element around the anchor is not necessary in html 5.

Comment: Good to know. I prefer having it there anyway; my CSS rules for vertical spacing are more consistent.

Comment: Nice answer, thanks. Except, all my category names are lower case when outputting category[0]

Comment: @Christian you probably want to use `capitalize`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19649009/titleize-jekyll-category

Comment: @kikito Yes, thats what I am actually using. But unfortunately, it doesn't capitalize both words (Like in: "Tech Talk"). Camelize for some reason doesn't work. I am going to try the join filter together with capitalize, maybe that helps.

Answer (score 1):

How about...

```
{% for category in site.categories %}
<h2 id = "{{ category[0] }}"> {{ category[0] }} </h2>
        <ul>
        {% for post in site.posts %}
            {% if post.category == category[0] %}
                 <li> <a href="{{ post.url }}"> {{ post.title }}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
<a href="#{{ category[0] }}-ref">&#8617</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Sure, it's pretty inefficient and generates a bunch of extra whitespace, but it gets the job done.

[The original was missing the  tags. Just added them. Also, to get ride of the whitespace, one can collapse everything from `for post in site.posts` to `endfor` onto a single line.]

Comment: No? Hmm... Does it come anywhere close? Works on my end.

Comment: It seems to come close, but It did the same thing that mine was doing roughly - it displays the appropriate amount of <a href="#{{ category[0] }}-ref">&#8617</a> links, but no links to any posts.

Answer (score 0):

```
        {% for post in site.categories.category %} 
        - OR -
        {% for post in site.categories.category[0] %}
```

Also, I'm not sure why kshep's example doesn't work...