# Titleize Jekyll category

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'd like to convert the printed category names of my posts into title case. I couldn't find a Liquid filter that would work. I tried using dashes and the camelcase filter, but no dice.

Alternatively, I'd like to print the category name as it's written in the YAML frontmatter.

For instance, for a post with:

```
category: Here's the Category
```

When I reference the name:

```
{% for cat in site.categories %}
    <h1>{{ cat[0] }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

I see "here's the category" on the page. I would like to see "Here's the Category" or even "Here's The Category," and I could replace (replace: 'The', 'the') the few articles that I wanted to be downcase.

**EDIT**

For anyone as desperate as I am, this disgusting hack works, where n is the max number of words you have in a category title.

```
{% for cat in site.categories %}
    {% assign words = cat[0] | split: ' ' %}
    <h1>{{ words[0] | capitalize | replace:'The','the'}} {{ words[1] | capitalize }} {{ words[2] }} {{ words[3] | capitalize }} {{ words[4] | capitalize }} {{ words[n] | capitalize }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

I'm going to leave the question unanswered in case someone knows a more elegant method.

Comment: I know this is an old thread and different solutions given here are useful for different situations. One thing that hadn't been mentioned it to use css, if it's suitable. Use text-transform and 'capitalize'. Together with @somkun's solution for removing any hyphened category names, this works nicely.

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve a part of what you want by using the `capitalize` filter:

#### Input

```
{{ 'capitalize me' | capitalize }}
```

#### Output

```
Capitalize me
```

[Source](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-basics/output#manipulation).

Another possibility, which I didn't test for its edge cases, is to use `join` and `camelize`:

```
{{ "here's the category" | join: '-' | camelize }}
```

It should print "Here's The Category", but camelize might have a problem with `here's`.

Comment: I don't think the join filter will work, as it seems to apply to elements of an array, not words in a string. But I was able to replace the spaces with '-' using the replace filter. Unfortunately, neither camelcase nor camelize are working for me. Even on non-dynamic strings, I can't get them to work. I've tried both "camelize" and "camelcase" on strings with dashes and underscores.

Comment: Oh, that's strange. What Jekyll version are you using?

Comment: That was my first thought, too, but I'm using the most recent, 1.2.1. Is it possible I updated awhile ago but didn't do something necessary to init the update? Like, do I have to rebuild the project? I'm running `jekyll serve --w` each time I boot up the project.

Comment: That's very strange... Well, in this case, your best bet might be writing a custom plugin. Ugh, sorry :(

Answer (score 2):

Just use `{{ category.first | capitalize }}` is OK for my case, without additional `''` on category.

Answer (score 1):

Name pages in Kabab-case as you want them to appear, then use replace:

```
{{ category.name | replace: '-', ' '}}
```

`Don't-Capitalize-the` becomes `Don't Capitalize the` and `Capitalize-The` becomes `Capitalize The`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually stepping through words 0 to n, one can use another for loop as follows:

```
{% for category in site.categories %}
  {% assign words = category | first | split: ' ' %}
  {% for word in words %}
    {{ word | capitalize | replace: 'The','the' }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is old but it helped me to solve my problem and it could help others.

The solution I came was:

```
{% for category in site.categories %}
  <a href="/{{category[0] | slugify }}/">
    {{category[0]}}
  </a>
{% endfor %}
```

This list all the blog categories (most used for building a menu)

It turns into:

```
<a href="/dicas/">
  Dicas
</a>

<a href="/diário-de-bordo/">
  Diário de bordo
</a>
```

Thank you for giving me a clue.
You can check another filters in: http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#filters

Answer (score 0):

This solutions is a little more overwrought, but you can adapt the [author data file solution from the Jekyll site](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/datafiles/#example-accessing-a-specific-author) to work with categories.

In your `_data` folder, make a file called `categories.yml`. Put in something like this:

```
my-first-category:
  name: My First Category

another-category:
  name: Another Category
```

Then, you can loop through your categories like this:

```
{% for category in site.categories %}
    {% assign category_slug = category[0] %}
    {% assign category_data = site.data.categories[category_slug] %}
    {% if category_data %}
        {{ category_data.name }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

*Side note: I'm not sure why I needed the `category_slug` assign. I didn't need it when looping through `post.categories`.*

This increases overhead by adding an extra file, but opens the door for other data that can get attached to objects like a category image or description. You can be more granular over your names. This is a pretty readable solution too, which is nice.

Answer (score 0):

I went the other way around. I hard coded my page title in Title case and use `downcase`, `upcase` and `capitalize` liquid filter in other pages.